# Outlook context menu with multiple calendar events selected

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing an outlook Add-In in VS2017. I need a context menu to appear when 1 or more calendar events are selected.  I can get a context menu to appear when a single calendar event is selected with the following XML:

```
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" loadImage="GetImage">
  <contextMenus>    
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCalendarItem">
        <button id="MyContextMenuCalendarItem"
            label="Copy To Google Calendar"
            image="Google_Calendar_Logo.png"
            onAction="CopyToGoogleCalendar_Click"/>
    </contextMenu>  
    </contextMenus>     
</customUI>
```

If I use the idMso "ContextMenuMultipleItems", the context menu will appear when multiple of any type (email, calendar, etc.) is selected.  I can not figure out the correct idMso for  context menu with multiple calendar events selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using the "ContextMenuMultipleItems" idMso works with the added "getVisible" method.  My XML now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" loadImage="GetImage">
  <contextMenus>    
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCalendarItem">
        <button id="MyContextMenuCalendarItem"
            label="Copy To Google Calendar"
                        image="Google_Calendar_Logo.png"
            onAction="CopyToGoogleCalendar_Click"/>
    </contextMenu>  
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMultipleItems">
        <button id="MyContextMenuMultipleItems" 
            label="Copy To Google Calendar" 
                        image="Google_Calendar_Logo.png"
                        getVisible="ContextMenuMultipleItems_IsVisible"
            onAction="CopyToGoogleCalendar_Click"/>
    </contextMenu>   
    </contextMenus>     
</customUI>
```

and the ContextMenuMultipleItems_IsVisible looks like:

```
public bool ContextMenuMultipleItems_IsVisible(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    if (control.Context is Outlook.Selection)
    {
        Outlook.Selection selection = control.Context as Outlook.Selection;
        if (selection[1] is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```